# Finding gap range from an array in python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am using numpy. I have an array `myarray` and I have a `min` and `max` value. `myarray` may not be sorted. So we can sort at first.

```
min = 1
max = 40
myarray = [3,9,10,11,12,26,30,38,39]
```

I want to get gap range between min and max from `myarray`. So the result should return all missing ranges in a dictionary, like this:

```
gap_range = [{"start": 1, "end": 2}, {"start": 4, "end": 8}, {"start": 13, "end": 25}, {"start": 27, "end": 29}, {"start": 31, "end": 37}, {"start": 40, "end": None}]
```

What could be an efficient way to do it? I have used a heuristic approach that loops through the array, but that seems inefficient.

Comment: Why are you producing a list of dictionaries? That will trash your performance; a 2xN numpy array will work a lot better.

Comment: Eventually, I have to arrange in dictionary and output in corresponding json

Comment: But then aranging in a dictionary will be inefficient anyway. So what do you want to do efficiently? Computing all starts and ends?

Comment: computing all start and end of gap ranges

Comment: O(n log n) sorting of array, O(log n) binary search for the possible location of min and max in myarray and O(n) iterate through it to create your dictionary? The sorting has still the worst time complexity, so optimizing other steps doesn't do much.

Comment: @RadosławŁazarz A Python for loop, while O(n), has a huge constant factor that will often make it slower than sorting a numpy array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute the gaps using vectorized numpy operations. Suppose you've computed the sorted segment of myarray that's between min and max, as in your example. Then you can compute the gaps like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> myarray = np.array([3,9,10,11,12,26,30,38,39])
>>> lowerBounds = (myarray+1)[:-1]
>>> lowerBounds
array([ 4, 10, 11, 12, 13, 27, 31, 39])
>>> upperBounds = (myarray-1)[1:]
>>> upperBounds
array([ 8,  9, 10, 11, 25, 29, 37, 38])
>>> mask = lowerBounds<=upperBounds
>>> mask
array([ True, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> upperBounds, lowerBounds = upperBounds[mask], lowerBounds[mask]
>>> upperBounds
array([ 8, 25, 29, 37])
>>> lowerBounds
array([ 4, 13, 27, 31])
```

Using vectorized operations will make the gap computation much faster, as Numpy uses C for loops instead of Python for loops. You can handle the corner cases of min and max in O(1) time, (or possibly along with the rest of the gaps, if you add min and max to the ends of your array).

As for the JSON requirement, you can send the same information with a dictionary of lists instead of a list of dictionaries, like so:

```
res = {"startPoints":[1, 4, 13, 27, 31] , "endPoints":[3, 8, 25, 29, 37]}
```

This will be a more efficient to construct and requires less bytes than the other version.

Comment: Thanks bpachev for your solution.